# Compile a *.f90 file using gfortran

Tags: compile, atom-editor

I have started using fortran. I am working on a Mac OSX version 10.10. As the fortran compiler, I installed **gfortran** and to make sure it is properly installed, I tried to issue gfortran on terminal and I got :

```
**gfortran:** **fatal error:** no input files

compilation terminated.
```

as the text editor, I installed **Atom 1.34.0. x64**. I also installed some useful fortran packages like : language-fortran and lintel. I wrote this simplest script and I saved it as **test.f90** :

```
program hello

        print *, "Hello, World!"

end program hello
```

But when I compile it from my terminal using :

```
Reyhanehs-MacBook-Pro:desktop reyhanehghh$ gfortran test.f90
```

nothing happens, no errors, no prints, nothing, the cursor just goes to the next line :

```
Reyhanehs-MacBook-Pro:desktop reyhanehghh$
```

I would be thankful if you could help me to get it compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command worked. As an output you now have an executable file named `a.out` (this is the default name). Run it by typing `./a.out` <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

To choose a custom name for the compiled executable use `-o` option:

```
gfortran -o my-executable test.f90
```

---

The exit status of your command would tell you the command succeeded, if you have checked it:

```
$ gfortran test.f90
$ echo $?
0
```

One of [Eric Raymond's 17 Unix Rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#Eric_Raymond's_17_Unix_Rules) is to "avoid unnecessary output". This is what `gfortran` does in this case.

Comment: I tried `$ echo $` and i got `0`. thanks a lot! it was very useful!